# Pyspark error when running on worker nodes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am experiencing an issue here when i run the following pyspark example on a local spark machine it is able to run perfectly fine. but when i start running it on a remote spark cluster i receive the following error on the worker nodes :-

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException:

Error from python worker:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 163, in _run_module_as_main

  mod_name, _Error)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 102, in _get_module_details

  loader = get_loader(mod_name)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 462, in get_loader

  return find_loader(fullname)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 472, in find_loader

  for importer in iter_importers(fullname):

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 428, in iter_importers

  __import__(pkg)

File "/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>

File "/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 34, in <module>

File "/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 31, in <module>

File "/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/find_spark_home.py", line 68

  print("Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching {0}".format(paths), file=sys.stderr)

                                                                                 ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

PYTHONPATH was:

  /spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip:/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip:/spark/jars/spark- 
  core_2.12-3.1.1.jar:/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip:/spark/python:

org.apache.spark.SparkException: EOFException occurred while reading the port number from pyspark.daemon's stdout

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:217)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:132)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:105)

    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:119)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:145)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)

    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)

    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)

    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)

    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)

    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is the example python script i was trying to run

```
   import pyspark
   import sys


   from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
   from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

 
   conf = SparkConf().setAppName('SparkTest')
   conf.setMaster('spark://xxxxx:7077')
   conf.setSparkHome('/spark/')


   spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
   sc = spark.sparkContext


   words = sc.parallelize(["abc","bcd","abc","ddd","eee","hjfghjgf","eee","sbc"])
   counts = words.count()

   print("Number of elements in RDD ".counts)
```

Additional information :-

- The python script i'm trying to run is on a windows machine setup with pyspark
  running on python 3.7 and the spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2 client
- Spark cluster is running on OCP cluster on python 3.7 and also spark 3.1.1

Any help would be very much appreciated . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. The reason for this issuse is:
As it said "/usr/lib/python2.7" is used in worker machine, which should not happend, because I am intended to use the anaconda env using python3.

I fixed it in this way.
Just link the system python (/usr/bin/python) to the python you want to use.

```
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root     11392 Apr 11  2018 pwscore
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root        78 Nov 17  2020 pydoc
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         8 Feb 10 17:57 pydoc3 -> pydoc3.6
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root        78 Nov 17  2020 pydoc3.6
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        50 Jun 23 19:37 python -> /home/hadoop/app/anaconda3/envs/bigdata/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         9 Feb 10 18:04 python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root      7144 Nov 17  2020 python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         9 Feb 10 17:57 python3 -> python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x   2 root root     11328 Nov 17  2020 python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x   2 root root     11328 Nov 17  2020 python3.6m
```

After this modification, spark works.